# Time Complexity of get operation on Google Protobuf deserialized repeated object

Tags: java, list, serialization, time-complexity, protocol-buffers

Let's say we create a proto file with repeated of some data type e.g.

```
message DocList{ 
    repeated string docId = 1;
}
```

Now we inserted objects to it's builder object in the following manner:

```
DocList.Builder docList = new DocList.newBuilder()
docList.addAllDocId(docIDlist);         // docIDList is ArrayList<String>
```

Now we perform the following get operation to retrieve an object at an index.

```
docList.getDocId(i);   // Some index i
```

**I want to know whether this get operation is O(1) or O(n) ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protobuf *ListValue* is backed by the *java.util.ArrayList*

```
if (!((mutable_bitField0_ & 0x00000001) == 0x00000001)) {
      values_ = new java.util.ArrayList<com.google.protobuf.Value>();
      mutable_bitField0_ |= 0x00000001;
}
```

hence it is O(1) for *get()*

[OpenJDK ArrayList](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java?av=f)

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
E elementData(int index) {
    return (E) elementData[index];
}
```